# cin doesn't work with typecaset

Tags: c++, input, type-conversion, cin

The following program doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c;
    cin >> (int)c;       // stat 1
    //scanf("%d", &c);   //stat 2; this when complied gives warning
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Q1. How to use `cin` to accept ASCII value of a character. I want to do it using a char variable.

Q2. If ensured that value input by user lies in the range of character, *stat 2* will **always** produce the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to be able to input e.g. `97` and for output get `'a'`? Then read into an actual `int` and cast the `int` variable to a character in the output. I.e. almost the opposite of what you do now:

```
int c;
std::cin >> c;
std::cout << static_cast<char>(c);
```

If you want to make sure that the input is a valid character, then use e.g. [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) or one of the other [character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: Thank you @Joachim-Pileborg. But my question is using a typecast (int) with `cin`. Explanation given by you solves the problem but I want to know about typecasting with `cin`.

Comment: @DeepakAggarwal `(int)c` doesn't work because you created a temporary.  `(int)c` is not *treat c as an int*.  it is *create an int that has the value of c*.

Comment: @DeepakAggarwal To be more precise, the input operator functions take non-const reference arguments, and `(int)c` creates an rvalue which can not be bound to a non-const reference.